# tomcat настройка

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, настройка, настройки

У меня сервер на tomcat. У меня есть страница admin.jsp что нужно настроить чтобы она открывалась как localhost/admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле `web.xml` вашего веб-приложения (каталог `WEB-INF` вашего веб-приложения), нужно сделать `mapping`(сопоставление) JSP-страницы с желаемым URL.

```
<servlet>   
           <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
           <jsp-file>/admin.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
           <servlet-name>Admin</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Также в вашем вопросе в строке `localhost/admin` отсутствует номер порта - по умолчанию, если вы не меняли номер порта, URL в адресной строке может выглядеть так: `localhost:8080/admin`. Чтобы в URL отсутствовал номер порта и он был вида `localhost/admin` нужно сменить номер порта на котором функционирует Tomcat на 80-й (общеизвестный порт для http-серверов). Для этого:

В каталоге conf в каталоге установки Tomcat отредактируйте файл `server.xml`. Найдите строку

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

и измените значение `port=8080` на `port=80` (и сохраните изменения в файле).